# Duplicating sheets with simple date from a named range

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

When I run the script to duplicate sheets with a date is give the tab a long date name `Thu Oct 18 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)`. I would like it to read in a `10/18/18` format.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)). Example from the link:

> ```
> // This formats the date as Greenwich Mean Time in the format
> // year-month-dateThour-minute-second.
> var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
> Logger.log(formattedDate);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ruben is correct but to give you the exact format based on your question you would do:

```
Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "MM-dd-yy");
```

Make a note that `new Date()` is replaced with your variable.  By default that pulls the current date and time, if you have a date value that you want to convert that is where it goes.

Timezones will matter as well:

GMT = Greenwich mean time
EST = Eastern Standard time
PST = Pacific Standard time
PDT = Pacific Dayligt time
and others...